# qml combobox item selection closes dynamic window

Tags: c++, qml, qtquick2

I have the MainForm.ui with a button and a slot connected to a signal coming from C++ side. Simplified example:

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
Window {
    visible: true
    width:430
    height:100
    id:mainWindow
    MainForm {

    }
}

// MainForm.ui.qml
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Rectangle {
    id: mainForm
    width: 800
    height: 400
    visible: true


    Button {
        text: "Hey"
        onClicked: {
            var component = Qt.createComponent("SecondForm.qml");
            if (component.status === Component.Error) {
                print(component.errorString())
                return;
            }

            var win = component.createObject(mainWindow);
            win.show();
            mainWindow.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

after receiving the signal I create a SecondForm and hide the main one.
On the SecondForm I have a tab and a combobox:

```
 // SecondForm.qml

import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Window {
    id:secondId
    width: 800
    height: 480
    title: "Second"

    TabView {
        id:tabview
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 5

        Tab {
            id:tab1
            ComboBox {
                model: [ "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4" ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I select any item in the combobox the application closes without even crash message or so. If I put the combobox on the first (main) form, it works well. Why does selecting the combobox items on dynamic component cause the closing? (Win7 64, qt5.6 alfa 32bit, vs2015)

Comment: Does the same thing happen with Qt 5.5?

Comment: @Mitch yes, I've just compiled and checked it

Comment: Can you try with a Dialog instead of a Window? Just a test.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo changed to Dialog{} and shown with open() - the same problem

Comment: Ok. It was just to test if It was related to windows. Could It be a bug with combobox, maybe.

Comment: You need to provide a complete example. If https://paste.kde.org/p03mtouga doesn't reproduce the issue for you, please change it so that it does, and then replace your existing snippets with it.

Comment: @Mitch done https://paste.kde.org/pk1nwtydr

Comment: Can you please edit your question with that code?

Comment: @Mitch sure, sorry for delay

Comment: If you don't hide the main window the application do not close...I'd say it is worth to report it as a bug.